# How to use request module to fetch urls with unicode characters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode, node-request

For example the link to my profile here on stack overflow looks like this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/607407/tomáš-zato
```

But if I copy it from browser bar, the actual value is:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/607407/tom%C3%A1%C5%A1-zato
```

You can paste either of these in your browser and it will work. But if I send non-encoded URL with unicode (to a different webpage) I get an error:

```
<html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>
Your browser sent an invalid request.
</body></html>
```

How to convert unicode characters in URL to their `%XX` variants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then `encodeurl` module helped me:

```
const encodeUrl = require('encodeurl')
```

Usage:

```
options.url = encodeUrl(options.url);
```